# Bind operator (=<<) with two parameters

Tags: haskell

Could not come up with a better subject title, unfortunately ... sorry.

I have a function that takes two pure parameters and returns a monadic value.
And I have two monadic values to be fed into it.
This is probably something stupid that I am missing.
I would normally use (=<<) if it was just one parameter but now I am stuck with two.

So I need a function with this type of signature

```
(a1 -> a2  -> m b) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m b
```

Hoogle does not give me anything.
I know I can just use 'do' notation  but I was wondering if this can be done  without?
Is it possible to curry with the bind operator something like this:

```
(function =<< value1) =<< value2
```

I thought 'liftM2' could be of use but it takes a function that returns a pure value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` in conjunction with `liftM2`:

```
join $ liftM2 function value1 value2
```

Comment: That is exactly what I thought of and wanted to try ... Let me check.

Comment: Yes, it works. I also missed a similar question as noted above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a such a function, but it's trivial to define one.

```
bind2 f m n = do
     m' <- m
     n' <- n
     f m' n'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I wanted to avoid 'do'notation. Instead of creating an extra function, I could wrap the whole thing in do notation. So it kind of defeats the point.

Comment: @r.sendecky Not entirely, `bind2 f` is a whole lot shorter than what I posted above, Haskell gears itself nicely towards building combinators like this, think `mapM`, `liftM`, `liftM2`, `sequence`, `sequence_`, `forM`...